# JQuery Click Handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, handler

I'm creating a bunch of `div`s and inserting thumbnail images through a referenced `js` file using a simple function.  Basically i'm trying to assign the click handler to each new `div` in the loop but for probably syntax reasons it isn't working.

This is my code ( updated )...

```
function makethumbs() {

    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {

        var backgroundUrl = script_vars + "/images/gallery/thumbs/g" + (i+1) + ".jpg",
            newdiv = $('<div />', {id: 'thumbnail'+i, width: 145, height: 84});
            newdiv.css({display:'inline', 
                        float:'left', 
                        margin:'2px 2px 0 0', 
                        color:'#000', 
                        fontSize:'18px', 
                        zIndex:0,
                        html:'P',
                        background: 'url(' + backgroundUrl + ')'
                       });
            newdiv.click(function() {
                $(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo('slow', 0);
            });

        $('#thumbholder').append(newdiv);
    }

    $('#arrowright').click(function() {
        var L = $('#thumbholder'),
            margL = parseInt(L.css('marginLeft'), 10),
            newMarg = (margL - 147) + 'px',
            anim = {opacity: 1};
            anim["marginLeft"] = newMarg;
        $('#thumbholder').stop(true, true).animate(anim, 400);

    });
}
```

Theres an extra click handler there too for `#arrowright` which works fine. Not sure if its a z ordering thing as the clickable arrow `div` is inside a container which overlays the thumbnail `div`s if that makes sense.

Comment: Any ideas on the above?  It`s basically not doing anything no errors no animation on click nothing..

Answer (score 2):

Why not keep on using jQuery ?

```
function makethumbs() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {

        var backgroundUrl = script_vars + "/images/gallery/thumbs/g" + (i+1) + ".jpg",
            newdiv = $('<div />', {id: 'thumbnail'+i, width: 145, height: 84});
            newdiv.css({display:'inline', 
                        float:'left', 
                        margin:'2px 2px 0 0', 
                        color:'#000', 
                        fontSize:'18px', 
                        zIndex:0,
                        html:'P',
                        background: 'url(' + backgroundUrl + ')'
                       });
            newdiv.click(function() {
                $(this).stop(true, true).fadeTo('slow', 0);
            });

        $('#thumbholder').append(newdiv);
    }

    $('#arrowright').click(function() {
        var L = $('#thumbholder'),
            margL = parseInt(L.css('marginLeft'), 10),
            newMarg = (margL - 147) + 'px',
            anim = {opacity: 1};
            anim["marginLeft"] = newMarg;
        $('#thumbholder').stop(true, true).animate(anim, 400);

    });
}​
```

as your main problem is trying to attach a click handler with jQuery syntax to a native JS DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for formatting my code :)  And for the answer i think i`ll try both ways as the javascript version in the other answer seems more straightforward - ie addEventListener.  

Well spotted i have no idea the differences between js and jquery :/

Comment: This is throwing HTMLDivElement has no method 'on' :/

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using. You should be using 1.8.3 now, or atleast something close.

Comment: As a sidenote, stop using those fracking square brackets for calculations, and use parenthesis, and don't wrap the jQuery object you create in jQuery once more. Use the code above, include the newest version of jQuery, make sure the function is called after the DOM is ready etc. and it should be working just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately using WP which have updated but only taking jQuery to v1.6.4 and i`ve read that WP requires strict version for it`s Admin backend so not sure how to proceed with that..

Running your above code on this v1.6.4 does nothing unfortunately :/

Comment: Ie it`s still throwing Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: @user1890408 - changed it a bit, maybe that helps? Running newest jQuery in wordpress is'nt a problem.

Comment: Still the same.  I`m trying to get WP to load the latest jQuery but that`s not working either ( complicating matters a bit ) - have a thread on that at ( http://wordpress.org/support/topic/load-newer-jquery-version?replies=3 )

Answer (score 0):

change `newDiv.click` to `$(newDiv).click` since you seem to be using jQuery; however if you want to continue using native javascript you can set an event for the element like so:

```
newDiv.addEventListener('click',function(){
//you code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks that looks promising!